# PostgreSQL nullable Foreign Key

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, key, nullable

I'm creating a postgreSQL table that has a foreign key that references itself, so it's a structure which is similar to a tree:

```
CREATE TABLE Person(
    ID serial PRIMARY KEY,
    Description text,
    Name varchar(5),
    ParentID serial,
    FOREIGN KEY (ParentID) REFERENCES Person(ID)
    );
```

The problem is that ParentID is automatically set to `NOT NULL` and therefore there can be no root in this tree. How do I make it nullable?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You probably want to change the type of your ParentID to an integer, which is the underlying type of serial.

```
CREATE TABLE Person(
    ID serial PRIMARY KEY,
    Description text,
    Name varchar(5),
    ParentID integer,
    FOREIGN KEY (ParentID) REFERENCES Person(ID)
);
```

The documentation for the integer and serial data type is available here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html

Comment: To explain a little: `serial` is basically a macro that expands into `integer default nextval('tablename_colname_seq')` and creates a sequence owned by the table. You don't need or want that for a foreign key, it's only useful for auto-generated key columns. So use `integer`. If you inspect the base table with `\dt Person` you'll see that the `id` column is really `integer` after the table creation.